# How do you access the elements repeating in Selenium within the <button>

Tags: c#, selenium

There are 2 buttons on the different pages, `BEREKEN` and `VERTEL`... Part 1 of code works fine, I can access and click the button, Part 2 of the code does not work. I am not sure why.

Part 1:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next(formstep1, 2);calculate(formstep1, 2);" ng-disabled=""><span>
    Bereken
</span></button>
```

Code used in `Selenium`:

```
searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-primary"));
        searchButton.Click();
```

Part 2:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next(formstep2, 3);calculate(formstep2, 3);" ng-disabled=""><span>
    Vertel ons iets over de woning
</span></button>
```

Code used in `Selenium`:

```
searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-primary"));
        searchButton.Click();
```

Comment: Correction on 1St line, 2 buttons on 2 different pages

Comment: Madhu please edit your post it is unclear

Comment: What you mean `code does not work`? You get an exception or just nothing happens?

Comment: Is it that it can't find the element, or an exception occurs or does it appear to click the element but nothing happens?

Comment: Please inspect the page and check the selector.Second time you might find 2 elements with .btn.btn-primary selector and the first one might be hidden. Create a selector using the part that is different like formstep1, formstep2 or other selector based on a parent.

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion: I get an error when running the code: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Comment: It could be as @lauda said and it's pulled in a hidden button, or it could be that there is something overlaying that button that means it can't be clicked

Comment: Could you try this `driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[contains(., 'Vertel')]"))`?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem when the original element, though not visible, is still part of the DOM. Therefor FindElement will locate the first element in the DOM which is not visible (in this case "Bereken") and return the error. If you search the DOM when the Vertel button is present you will probably find multiple elements with the class you are matching on.

For example the ng-click attribute is unique and you can match on a substring of its value like this:

```
//Bereken
berekenButton = FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[ng-click*='formstep1']"));

//Vertel
vertelButton = FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[ng-click*='formstep2']"));
```

^ matches on prefix, # matches on suffix, * matches on substring.